# PostgreSQL add new table to existing schema

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL as my relational database and I have many related tables like the main two tables: table 1 and table 2 but now I added 3 more tables like table 3, table 4, and table 5. So, the main problem is here,

1. *I want to make one new table for the city as table 6 from the existing tables (table 3,4,5) but I don't know how can I integrate all city names in this one table and relate this table by a foreign key to table 3,4,5 because each table 3,4,5 have more than 30,000 rows.*
2. *As I mentioned I already have a country table (table 2) having country_id and country_name so I also want to integrate the country information from table 3,4,5 to the main country table (table 2) but it cannot affect the existing country_id and country_name because its already connect to other tables too and connect this table back to table 3,4,5 by country_id foreign key.*

Table 1:

| vid | name | ..... | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ship1 | ...... | 41 |
| 14 | ship2 | ...... | 44 |
| 41 | ship4 | ...... | 50 |

Table 2:

| country_id | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | Japan |
| 44 | USA |
| 50 | china |
| ........ | ..... |

Table 3:

| mid | name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | JHON | MUBAI | INDIA |
| 35 | ADAN | LONDON | UNITED KINGDOM |
| 46 | SMITH | JAKARTA | INDONESIA |
| ... | ... | .... | ...... |

Table 4:

| oid | name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | ABC | BEIJING | CHINA |
| 24 | DEF | LONDON | UNITED KINGDOM |
| 30 | GHI | KOLALMP | MALASIA |
| ... | ... | .... | ...... |

Table 5:

| Bid | name | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | ABC | BEIJING | CHINA |
| 29 | DEF | KARACHI | PAKISTAN |
| 40 | GHI | KOLALMP | MALASIA |
| ... | ... | .... | ...... |

So, My final tables will look like:

Table 6:

| city_id | city_name | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | BEIJING | 50 |
| 15 | LONDON | 21 |
| 20 | KOLALMPOR | 65 |
| ... | ... | .... |

Table 7 (for 3,4,5):

| o/b/mid | name | city_id | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | JHON | 01 | 41 |
| 35 | ADAN | 45 | 60 |
| 46 | SMITH | 60 | 50 |
| ... | ... | .... | ...... |

Comment: You can write Stored procedure or Function that collects all the distinct 'cities' from tables 3 to 5, and populate 'table 6'. Make an attempt.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why did you divided into 3 tables like (table 3,4 and 5) instead of keeping them in a single table like table 7(similar)?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN actually its not the same Table, these are different table 3,4,5 like manager, owner and builder but table structure are same so for these three tables i want a result in 3 other tables which will be look like table 7 . manager have their own , id, name, city and country like these owner and builder have there own but i want to connect all these table by foreign key to city and country table.

Answer (score 0):

Why do tables 3,4 and 5 have foreign key for only country_id(actually, in your case there is a relation between table_3/4/5.country and table_2.country_name) that references table 2? They should have similar foreign key for your table 6 on city_id.

In order to fill table 6 you should use the same way that you have used to fill table 2. And in this case you can experience early arriving facts which generally belongs to data warehouse environment. In case of early arriving facts you set and a default values or null and then periodically correct them.

If your customer select their cities from a dropdown box(maybe a GUI) then it means you already fill table 6 on your own(you are not giving chance to them to input their own new cities) or you provide them a textbox to write their own cities(you are giving chance to them to input their own new cities). So, in this case on the application layer you need to check if that city in your table 6 or not. If not, you can create a new entry for table 6 or set related city information to a default value or null to handle them later.

Comment: OK so the main problem is that these all tables is already available in my relational database which have thousand of rows so making small change can make a big problem for me. Table 1 is main table here which is connected to table 2,3,4,5 such as ship[vid(pk),name,country_id,mid,bid,oid] so table 1 is connected to table 2 by country_id. if you see table 3,4,5 have also country and city name  which i want that this country name need to be added to exiting country table 2 because some country name is already there but some needed to be add and give you new country id too . continue.....

Comment: also want to extract the city name from table  3,4,5 and create new city table city[city_id, city_name,country_id] connect back to table 3,4,5 by city_id so table 3 will be look like manager[mid,name,city_id, country_id].......

Comment: Then, you are pointing out Anand Sowmithiran' s solution. To keep in mind, instead of splitting them creating a table set like, create table roles(role_id int, role_name); create table b_o_m_id(id int, role_id int, name char, city_id int, country_id int); would be better. The operational cost will pile up with time in current design. To sum up, as Anand Sowmithiran stated, create a periodical job to collect distinct cities from table 3, 4 and 5 to insert your city table.